# Extend gnome-control-center’s list of keyboard layouts

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout

While looking for my problem of https://askubuntu.com/questions/367777/keyboad-layout-in-13-10-modified-symbols-do-not-apply, I noticed that `gnome-control-center region layouts` has a list of keyboard layouts that is not directly related to the ones found in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`. For example, on my German machine it lists ‘Englisch (Colemak)’ and ‘English (Britisch, Colemak)’ as keyboard layouts, both are not found in the original files, but obviously translations.

So, my question is: Where does gnome-control-center get its list of keyboard layouts from? Can it be extended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list can be found in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`, and it can be extended.

The translations can be found in `xkeyboard-config.mo` for the respective language.